# Retrofit2: serializer doesn't get called for @Field-annotated parameters

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, okhttp

I need to send HTTP PUT request with custom JSON object in one of request's parameter. Here is a problem: when I use it with Retrofit2, my serializer doesn't called.

My object should looks like this:

```
{
    "ignore":["item1", "item2"]
}
```

When I call it directly it works well:

```
final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, new MyModelSerializer())
        .create();
String s = gson.toJson(new MyModel(MyModel.ActionName.ACCEPT, new ArrayList<String>()));
Log.d("tag", s);
```

I get `{"accept":[]}`. But when I call it with Retrofit I see in logs this: `D/OkHttp: name=abc&items=ru.bartwell.myapp.MyModel%4010a3d8b`

I make request with this code:

```
try {
    MyModel myModel = new MyModel(MyModel.ActionName.ACCEPT, new ArrayList<String>());
    Response<ResultModel> response = getMyApi().getResult(1, "abc", myModel).execute();
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        ResultModel resultModel = response.body();
        // handle resultModel
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**MyApi**:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@PUT("path/{id}")
Call<ResultModel> getResult(@Path("id") long item, @Field("name") @NonNull String name, @Field("items") @NonNull MyModel myModel);
```

**getMyApi()** method:

```
public static MyApi getMyApi() {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(MyModel.class, new MyModelSerializer())
        .create();

    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.END_POINT_MY_API)
            .client(MyOkHttpClient.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()
            .create(MyApi.class);
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class MyModel {
    @NonNull
    private ActionName mActionName;
    @NonNull
    private List<String> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyModel(@NonNull final ActionName actionName, @NonNull final List<String> items) {
        mActionName = actionName;
        mItems = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ActionName getActionName() {
        return mActionName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public List<String> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    public enum ActionName {
        ACCEPT("accept"), DECLINE("decline"), IGNORE("ignore");

        private String mName;

        ActionName(@NonNull final String name) {
            mName = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return mName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Serializer**:

```
public class MyModelSerializer implements JsonSerializer<MyModel> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(@NonNull MyModel src, @NonNull Type typeOfSrc, @NonNull JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.add(src.getActionName().getName(), new Gson().toJsonTree(src.getItems()));
        return obj;
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `@Field`-annotated parameters are serialized with `stringConverter`. To override the default behavior, you just need to add another `Converter.Factory` with the `stringConverter` method overridden:

```java
.addConverterFactory(new Converter.Factory() {
    @Override
    public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
        // Example check for supported classes
        if ( type instanceof Class ) {
            final Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) type;
            if ( MyModel.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ) {
                return (Converter<Object, String>) value -> gson.toJson(value, type);
            }
        }
        return super.stringConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
    }
})
```

Then your query parameter string will look like this:

> name=abc&items=%7B%22accept%22%3A%5B%5D%7D

(this `%7B%22accept%22%3A%5B%5D%7D'` is URI-encoded `{"accept":[]}`).

A few side-notes:

- `Gson` instances are thread-safe and can be created once per the whole application (And this is perfectly fine to pass the single instance to all your components).
- Your `MyModelSerializer` can be improved: you should not create a `Gson` instance there since deserializers are bound to the `Gson` instance configuration, so you have to delegate the serialization via the given context like `context.serialize(myModel.mItems, itemsType)`, where `itemsType` is `new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType()`.